# Batch file in windows scheduler

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, task-scheduler

```
set PATH=C:\Users\...
call date2.cmd
md %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY%
cd %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY%
```

So, I set my path to the folder that has PSFTP for me to run and run a file that will get the current date. It then makes a new folder with that date and places every file from the FTP into that folder. The problem I'm having is that it is actually placing the ned file and all those files into `Windows/system32` when it's run by the task scheduler. If I run the batch file manually, then it works correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "set PATH" tells CMD where to look for commands, it is a completely different thing from the current working directory, which as you found out you have to set with the CD command.  You can make your comment into an answer and accept it as the solution to your problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for the input.  I will do that.  Apparently I have to wait 8 hars to answer my question, so I will wait until then.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I might have fixed the issue. I found that in the batch I might have to go to the specific path when running it in windows scheduler on Win 7. So it looks like this: set PATH=C:\Users... call date2.cmd cd\Users... md %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY% cd %DT_MM%-%DT_DD%-%DT_YYYY% Apparently, when running in scheduler, it opens cmd with a default path and the path I set at the beginning doesn't keep the path for creating a dir. I will report back with results later after more testing.